# TypeScript error on input value in template loop through object keys in Vue 3 (Nuxt 3)

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I migrate a Nuxt app from version 2 to 3 currently and with that also introducing TypeScript into the stack. In one of my components template I loop through a set of unknown object keys to create a list of radio or checkbox inputs.

```
<template
    v-for="(optionValue, optionKey) in options"
    :key="`filter-option-${optionKey}`"
>
    <input
        :id="optionKey.toString()"
        v-model="selection"
        class="filter-options-input visually-hidden"
        :value="optionKey"
        :name="name"
        :type="type"
    >
    <label
        :for="optionKey.toString()"
        :class="['filter-options-label', `is-${type}`]"
    >
        {{ optionValue }}
    </label>
</template>
```

The code creates the required fields like expected but what I can't get fixed is the following TypeScript error on the `<input>`s `:value` attribute:

> An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name. ts(1117)

Here it complains:
[image]

The type definition for `options` looks like this:

```
type Option = {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

The actual data would look like this:

```
{
    "portrait":"Hochformat",
    "landscape":"Querformat",
    "square":"Quadratisch"
}
```

or like this:

```
{
    "akane-akane": "Akane, Akane",
    "anita-staud": "Staud, Anita",
    "anne-marie-chatelier": "Chatelier, Anne-Marie",
    "anneli-schuetz": "Schütz, Anneli",
    "annette-gundermann": "Gundermann, Annette",
    "arno-mohr": "Mohr, Arno",
    ...
}
```

What does TypeScript want to tell me here and how can I fix the error message?

Here is the reproduction in a Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/agitated-mendeleev-ypytew?file=%2Fcomponents%2Finput-list.vue&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A14%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A34%2C%22startColumn%22%3A14%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A34%7D%5D

Comment: Thanks for your reply but as I use here radio and checkbox inputs I have to set value so Vue knows which value is set when the use selects one of them. Like described here for example: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#checkbox.
Otherwise I would just get 'on' as a value for every input.

Comment: Yes you are right for checkbox and radio you need value sorry I missed that part.

Comment: But in your case `optionKey` is an object I think you need to do `optionKey.key` did you try that?

Comment: Thanks @nicholasnet, as said the code actually works. I'm using here the `v-for` as documented for objects (https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for-with-an-object) so `optionKey`is really just the key and not the object itself. I'm just wondering why TypeScript complains and how I can solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem:**
is related to a wrong typing of `v-model` as an alias of `InputHTMLAttributes.value`. According to [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#form-input-bindings), `v-model` on

> `<input type="checkbox">` *and* `<input type="radio">` *use* `checked` *property* ...

... which has nothing to do with the `value` property.

---

I initially thought it's coming from `nuxt` (because it was the only dependency in the sandbox you linked and I'm not seeing the same in a fresh `vue` project), so I opened [this ticket](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/19079) on their repo.

However, it turns out the culprit for the wrong typing is Volar, an IDE extension used by Codesandbox (and, most likely, by your IDE).

If you want to pursue this further, feel free to raise an issue with Volar, on their repo.

---

**Fixes**:

1. Disable Volar
2. circumvent the problem using `v-bind` syntax:

```html
<input
  :id="optionKey.toString()"
  v-model="selection"
  class="filter-options-input visually-hidden"
  v-bind="{ value: optionKey, name, type }"
/>
```

3. Ignore it with a template ignore:

```html
<input
  ...
  v-model="selection"
  ...
  :data-foo="/* ts-ignore */"
  :value="optionKey"
  ...
/>
```

Comment: Thanks @tao for your answer. You're right the final code in the browser actually works. Its just TypeScript that isn't satisfied here and I don't get why. But isn't there a better way than just ignoring it or creating a separate template?

Comment: Ah thanks for the explanation @tao! That makes sense. So I have to tell TypeScript somehow that this can only be of `type="radio"` or `type="checkbox"`but nothing else, right?

Comment: Yes, that should remove the error. What's the exact rule generating the error? You'll see it when hovering the error.

Comment: Thats the error message:

_An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name. ts(1117)_

Comment: (property) InputHTMLAttributes.value?: any

Comment: Could you create a codesandbox.io (or similar)? It should have at least the `package.json` and the component where you're seeing this. + the minimum to repro the issue.

Comment: Here is the reproduction in a Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/agitated-mendeleev-ypytew?file=%2Fcomponents%2Finput-list.vue&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A14%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A34%2C%22startColumn%22%3A14%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A34%7D%5D

Comment: Hey @tao, thank you so much for your efforts here, filing the ticket and updating your answer with the available fixes! Your explanation is really helpful to understand better what the actual issue is. Great work!
I found the `v-bind` solution the most "elegant" so far. For some strange reason it only works if I move `v-model` after the  `v-bind` directive. The other way round I would get an error on the `v-model` directive.
But in the end you're right I'm using Volar in VSCode and disabling that isn't really an option but I will file an issue on vuejs/language-tools as Daniel suggested.

Comment: Files an issue in the vue language tools: https://github.com/vuejs/language-tools/issues/2399. Lets see.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out the issue wasn't in the code but in my IDE. The Volar extension that I use had an inaccurate prop type definition for `v-model`.
This got now fixed in vuejs/language-tools with version `1.1.3` (2023/2/18).